# Install module in magento 2 on hosting

Tags: magento2, command-line

pls help me, install module in hosting, I upload module on hosting using filezilla but module cant not run, because i dont know  run cmd `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
on host server. My english isn't good, hope everyone understands.

Comment: which type of access you have on filezilla is it sftp?

Comment: do you have SSH access?

Answer (score 0):

you can use php function for run command and create a php file Magento 2 root 
 exec("php bin/magento setup:upgrade",$output);

But first check php path Then try

Comment: In localhost exec("php bin/magento setup:upgrade",$output); var_dump($output);it working, but on hosting I had printed var_dump($output) return $output array empty

Comment: Please follow that code
<?php
 /*Install plugin and update schema*/
 exec("whereis php", $output_first, $return_first);
 $manyPaths  = explode(' ',$output_first[0]);
 $manyPaths[] = 'php';
 echo "<pre>";
 foreach ($manyPaths as $key => $value) {
  exec("$value bin/magento setup:upgrade",$output);
  if(!empty($output)){   
   print_r($output);
   exec('chmod 777 -R var/');
   break;
  }
 }
 if(empty($output)){
  echo "Please Use Command For Installation<br>";
 }
 exec('chmod 777 -R var/');
 echo "Please give permission 777 var folder";
?>

Comment: thanks you for answer ,but It still not working,still return array empty :(  :(

Answer (score 0):

im try run exec("php bin/magento setup:upgrade",$output); but return array empty

[image]